# I am really stuck with this problem, let b(x) be a system of neighoruhoods of point x of the infinite set X with cofinite

Tags: general-topology

let b(x) be a system of neighoruhoods of point x of the infinite set X on which there is some topology, that is stronger than cofinite topology. Prove that ⋃U∈b(x)(X\U) = X{x}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

So $\mathcal{B}(x)$ is a base of neighbourhoods for $x$.

We have to show that $$\bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{B}(x)} (X\setminus U) = X\setminus\{x\}$$

As $x \in U$ for all $U \in \mathcal{B}(x)$, it’s clear that $X\setminus U \subseteq X\setminus \{x\}$, and so the union on the left is also a subset of the right hand side.

If $y \in X\setminus \{x\}$, we use the assumption that $X$ has a finer topology then the cofinite one to observe that $X\setminus \{y\}$ is open in $X$ (it’s cofinite) and a neighbourhood of $x$ (as $y \neq x$). So for some $U \in \mathcal{B}(x)$ we have $x \in U \subseteq X\setminus \{y\}$. It follows that $y \in X\setminus U$ for that $U$ and so $y$ is a member of the left hand union.

This shows two inclusions hence equality.

Comment: how did we find that  X∖{y} is open?

Comment: @AngelaDevis like I said: it’s cofinite

Comment: what do you mean in this:  and a neighbourhood of x (as y≠x)?

Comment: Because $x \notin Y\setminus \{y\}$ by definition.